# Second Degree Diophantine Equation, When exists solutions?

Tags: diophantine-equations

In second degree diophantine equations, ax<sup>2</sup>+bxy+cy<sup>2</sup>+dx+ey+f=0,

Is there a theorem or criterion that allows us to decide whether or not any second degree diophantine equation has solutions without resolution?

Thank you,

Javier

Comment: Related [Second degree Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181380/second-degree-diophantine-equations)

Comment: You can use the Hasse-Minkowski theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem

Comment: [Manders&Adleman. NP-complete decision problems for quadratic polynomials](https://doi.org/10.1145/800113.803627)

Answer (score 2):

There is a procedure that can be learned by a beginner. It is sufficiently messy that I won't give the giant expressions when attempting to finish using symbols.

First, make a new variable $z$ and make the polynomial homogeneous. If there are integers $x,y,z$ that make the expression below zero, then there are **rational** solutions to your original problem

$$ a x^2 + bxy + c y^2 + dzx + e yz + f z^2 $$

Next, the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is

$$
H=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2a&b&d \\
b&2c&e \\
d&e&2f
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Next, there is a procedure for constructing $P^T H P = D,$  where $P$ is rational determinant $\pm 1$  and $D$ is rational diagonal.

Here is an example I made up.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 9 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 3 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 5 \\ 
7 & 5 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 104 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

I deliberately adjust $P$ to $PW,$ where I chose $W$ to be the diagonal matrix $1,2,3.$ The new version is

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -3  & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 27 &   11   & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 3 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 5 \\ 
7 & 5 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -   3   &  - 27 \\ 
0 & 2 &   11  \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  6  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -   312  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Next are there any rational solutions to
$$ 2 u^2 + 6 v^2 - 312 w^2 = 0, $$ or
$$  u^2 + 3 v^2 - 156 w^2 = 0. $$
If there are rational solutions we get integer solutions by multiplying by a common denominator.

This is the province of Legendre's theorem on indefinite ternaries.

We note
$$ 156 = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13.
 $$
$  u^2 + 3 v^2 - 156 w^2 = 0. $
We can express $12 = 9 + 3\cdot 1$  and $13 =1 + 3 \cdot 4 $

The standard way to combine these expressions gives two versions,
$$ 156 = 9^2 + 3 \cdot 5^2 
 = 3^2 + 3 \cdot 7^2 
 $$

We have constructed two solutions to our intermediate problem $  u^2 + 3 v^2 - 156 w^2 = 0. $
One is $u=9, \; v = 5, \; w = 1.$  Another is $u=3, \; v = 7, \; w = 1.$

It happens that there is a way to parametrize all integer triples that satisfy  $ x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 5yz+7zx+3xy=0 $ The idea goes back to Fricke and Klein (1897). As we now know there are integer solutions to

$$x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 5yz+7zx+3xy=0$$

3      1      3 transposed        3      1     -1
1     -5     -1 transposed       $$   x = 3 p^2 + pq + 3 q^2$$
$$ y = p^2 - 5pq - q^2  $$
$$ z = -p^2 +3pq -3 q^2  $$  1     -5      3
-1      3     -3 transposed        3     -1     -3

tells us infinitely many integer solutions
$$   x = 3 p^2 + pq + 3 q^2$$
$$ y = p^2 - 5pq - q^2  $$
$$ z = -p^2 +3pq -3 q^2  $$
Note how very much this resembles the parameterization of Pythagorean Triples.

A little more work would provide parameterizations of all solutions.

-3      1     -3 transposed       -3     -1      1
-1     -5      1 transposed        1     -5      3
1      3      3 transposed       -3      1      3

is better, as it tells us directly when we can have $z=+1.$ Only finitely many times as the last binary is positive definite.
$$   x = -3 p^2 + pq - 3 q^2$$
$$ y = -p^2 - 5pq + q^2  $$
$$ z = p^2 +3pq +3 q^2  $$

Yep, the form for $z$ keeps coming up discriminant $-3,$ therefore positive. Still, we then have a few solutions to
$x^2 + 3 y^2 + 5  + 5y+7x+3xy=0$

Comment: so if u <sup>2</sup> +3v<sup>2</sup>−156w<sup>2</sup>=0 has integer solutions, x<sup>2</sup>+3y<sup>2</sup>+5+5y+7x+3xy=0 has integer solution too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole theory about this. It's beautiful too. See these books for instance:

- [Binary Quadratic Forms: An Algorithmic Approach](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540463672)
  by Bachmann and  Vollmer
- [Rational Quadratic Forms](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html) by Cassels

Answer (score 0):

All second degree equations are solvable for one of the variables using the quadratic equation.

\begin{equation}
ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies x = -\frac{\pm\sqrt{(b y + d)^2 - 4 a (y (c y + e) + f)} + b y + d}{2 a}
\quad \text{ for }\quad a\ne0\\
\text{or}\quad x = -\frac{y (c y + e) + f}{b y + d}\quad\text{ for }\quad  a = 0 \land b y + d\ne0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\implies y = -\frac{\pm\sqrt{(b x + e)^2 - 4 c (x (a x + d) + f)} + b x + e}{2 c}
\quad\text{for}\quad c\ne0\\
\text{or}\quad y = -\frac{x (a x + d) + f}{b x + e}
\quad \text{for}\quad c = 0 \land b x + e\ne0
\end{equation}

As long as the discriminant (the part under the radical) is non-negative, there are unlimited solutions.

Comment: this isn't my question

Comment: @Javier Álvarez You asked "Is there a theorem or criterion that allows us to decide whether or not any second degree diophantine equation has solutions without resolution?" My answer was that a non-negative discriminant indicates real solutions as opposed to complex ones.